# linux korn shell /../.envfile [a]..[b]..[c] meaning

Tags: linux, ksh, environment

I get an error message when logging in that is similar to below:

[image]

Can someone please help me understanding the numbers in brackets ? In case these are some line numbers in referenced files, how to track down to which file, what line content ?

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax is:

```
filename[lineno]: functionname[lineno]: nestedfunction[lineno]: error
```

For example:

```
$ cat demo
function bar { invalid; }
function foo { bar; }
foo

$ ksh demo
demo[3]: foo[2]: bar[1]: invalid: not found [No such file or directory]
```

When you use `.` to source a file instead of calling a function, you see the same thing but with `.` as the name. I don't know why it doesn't show the filename instead, but hey:

```
$ cat foo
. ./bar

$ cat bar
# dummy line
. ./baz

$ cat baz
# dummy line
# dummy line
invalid

$ ksh foo
foo[1]: .[2]: .[3]: invalid: not found [No such file or directory]
```

You can start with your `.envfile`, look on line 6, follow the file it sources, look at line 65, follow the file it sources, look at line 737, follow the line it sources, and that should be your file with bad line terminators.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I will check it out.